# Prevent Entity Framework query from being evaluated locally

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this query that is being partially evaluated locally and I am wondering how to prevent it.
It seems to be the conditional select that is causing the problem.

```
var fetchQuery = (
  from udg in _entities.UberDirectGroups.AsNoTracking()

  join uber in _entities.Ubers.AsNoTracking()
      on udg.Id equals uber.Id

  let memberCount = (
     from t in _entities.UberDirects.AsNoTracking()
     join u in _entities.Ubers.AsNoTracking()
         on t.UberToId equals u.Id
     where t.UberFromId == udg.Id && !u.Deleted
     select u.UberTypeId == (byte)UberType.User ? 1 : 
         u.UberTypeId == (byte)UberType.Department ? u.Department.Users.Where(user => user.Deleted == false).Count() :
         u.UberTypeId == (byte)UberType.Office ? u.tblOffice.tblDepartment.SelectMany(d => d.Users).Where(user => user.Deleted == false).Count() :
         u.UberTypeId == (byte)UberType.ProjectGroup ? u.Group.GroupMembers.Select(pm => pm.User).Where(user => user.Deleted == false).Count() :
         u.UberTypeId == (byte)UberType.Role ? _entities.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleDataId == u.tblRoleData.Id).Select(r => r.tblUser).Where(user => user.Deleted == false).Count() : 0
  ).Sum()

  where
      udg != null &&
      uber != null &&
      uber.InstanceId == instanceId &&
      (!isSearch || udg.Name.Contains(searchText))

  select new TargetGroupProjection
  {
      id = udg.Id,
      name = udg.Name,
      created = uber.Date,
      toCount = memberCount
  }
  );
```

Comment: It's probable the .Sum() at the end that doesn't defer the execution until the other conditions are included in the query.

Comment: EF Core 2 had client evaluation because its query translation engine was not good enough to do without it.  The easiest thing is to try upgrading to EF Core 3, so long as you're not targeting .NET Framework.